# Angular 2 Different Template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I would like to ask, how to create a layout different on each other. For example, I have a Login page so basically it has no header (navigation bar), after login it will redirect to homepage which has a header so that means different layout. I'm just starting to learn angular 2. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at *ngIf... You can define whole blocks of code that either show or hide based on a Boolean value.

For example, from my app:

```
 <div *ngIf="isSuccess" class="ui-grid-row form-group">
    <div class="ui-grid-col-12">
       <p>You have successfully verified your email address. We will take you to the login screen.</p>
       <p>Thank you for signing up and we wish you the best.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!isSuccess" class="ui-grid-row form-group">
   <div class="ui-grid-col-12">
      <p>Your email address verification has failed. Please resend the verification and try again.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for changes on the same template John Baird has answered the questions, in case you are looking to have a different template all together you should be looking to create a component and route.
Create a new component ng g component.
Create a route "/toComponent".

Redirect from you login component to this new formed component.
you might wana look at 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html